# Inserting timestamp array in MySQL DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to insert an array of dates in database but the program does not behave. I'm doing something wrong.

**This insert *NULL*:**

```
// initialize the array with first date
$dates = array(strtotime("+17 days", strtotime($period_startdate)));
// now loop 26 times to get the next 26 dates
for ($i = 1; $i <= 26; $i++) {
    // add 14 days to previous date in the array
    $dates[] = strtotime("+14 days", $dates[$i-1]);
}
// echo the results
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    // prepare and bind for paydates
    $insertpaydates= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO paydates (payroll_secret_id,paydate) VALUES (?,?)");
    $insertpaydates->bind_param("ss",$secret_id,$dates[$date]);
}
```

**This insert only one row and wrong date (1970-01-01)**

```
// initialize the array with first date
$dates = array(strtotime("+17 days", strtotime($period_startdate)));
// now loop 26 times to get the next 26 dates
for ($i = 1; $i <= 26; $i++) {
    // add 14 days to previous date in the array
    $dates[] = strtotime("+14 days", $dates[$i-1]);
}
// echo the results
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $Item_Date[$date] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Item_Date[$date]));
    // prepare and bind for paydates
    $insertpaydates= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO paydates (payroll_secret_id,paydate) VALUES (?,?)");
    $insertpaydates->bind_param("ss",$secret_id,$Item_Date[$date] );
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$period_startdate`?

Comment: @nogad: this returns 0000-00-00

Comment: @JohnConde: $period_startdate is the value extracted from jquery ui calendar datepicker. It is post above the for loop $period_startdate = $_POST['period_startdate'];

Comment: But *what is the value*?

Comment: @JohnConde: a random jquery date picked by the user format is 2016-04-02 it's inserted in a Mysql date column.

Comment: @SebastianFarham See my answer below.

Comment: *"a random jquery date picked by the user format is 2016-04-02"* - "date" or "dates"? If it's in the plural form, make sure the date/POST array from its source is indeed treated as an array. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="period_startdate[]">` - if it's just a single date for one record, why the `foreach`? I think you should include all essential parts of your html/php - Run a var_dump on everything and see what is passed through or not and check for errors on the query using `mysqli_error($db)`. The column should also be a `DATE` type and not `DATETIME`, should this be the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: it's a single date...

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I know the date is getting captured because I actually store the date in another date column in another table and it prints on the page. When I var_dump($dates) this what I get `array(27) { [0]=> int(1492639200) [1]=> int(1493848800) [2]=> int(1495058400) [3]=> int(1496268000) [4]=> int(1497477600) [5]=> int(1498687200) [6]=> int(1499896800) [7]=> int(1501106400) [8]=> int(1502316000) [9]=>... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong use of Foreach

The problem on the first code snippet is inside the foreach loop. When you loop through an array, the second parameter will be the actual entry of the array, not just the key. So instead of using `$dates[$date]` you should simply use `$date` inside your loop.

### Execute Query Inside Loop

You also have to execute the query for each time you bind new parameters to the statement, or else you will just override the old parameters and do a single execution after the loop. So you should add the execute to the `foreach`-loop so that it writes on each iteration.

### Prepare Statements Outside Loops

A third thing you should do to improve the performance of your code is to move the SQL Prepare statement to outside the loop. Instead of preparing the statement 26 times you can only do it once, and then execute it with different values 26 times. This will make a big difference in the execution time.

### Timestamps != DateTime

In the comments below to this post it seems like you are using a bad combination of data and data types in the MySQL database. You're trying to write an integer timestamp to a DateTime field. You should convert it into a valid date format before writing it.

So final code would be:

```
// Convert our $_POST value to a timestamp.
$period_startdate = strtotime($period_startdate);

// We init the first date value.
$dates = array(
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+17 days", $period_startdate)), 
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 26; $i++) {
    // Add 14 days to previous date in the array.
    // Notice we have to convert the previous date in the array to a timestamp using strtotime().
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+14 days", strtotime($dates[$i-1])));
}

// We prepare our statement before the loop to avoid preparing it 
// multiple times. This saves performance.
$insertpaydates = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO paydates (payroll_secret_id,paydate) VALUES (?,?)");

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    // Here we change from $dates[$date] to simply $date
    $insertpaydates->bind_param("ss", $secret_id, $date);
    // Here we execute the query for each date.
    $insertpaydates->execute();
}
```

Comment: I added execute() to the loop.

Comment: Did you add the execute() statement that I added to the edit just now?

Comment: Yes I did. It excutes and insert the row but the date returns zeros

Comment: @SebastianFarham Do a `var_dump($dates);` before the `foreach` and make sure it contains 26 dates.

Comment: `array(27) { [0]=> int(1492639200) [1]=> int(1493848800) [2]=> int(1495058400) [3]=> int(1496268000) [4]=> int(1497477600) [5]=> int(1498687200) [6]=> int(1499896800) [7]=> int(1501106400) [8]=> int(1502316000) [9]=>... }`

Comment: Yes, that's because your code is generating timestamps. `strtotime()` turns a string, to a timestamp which is in integer format. If you want to save it in datetime format you need to save it as strings. I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks bro. Works. Just make sure add the missing parenthesis here `$dates[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+14 days", strtotime($dates[$i-1])));` and remove the coma here `$dates = array(
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+17 days", $period_startdate)), 
);`